# Odoo: Display a field in tree view depending on value of another field in the model

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a tree view in which I want to display a column depending on the value of another field. To be specific, in the `Inventory` app, I want to add a column in the tree view when the picking type is 'Internal Transfers'. I do not want to show the same column in any other picking type.

Please note, I am customizing this in Odoo Enterprise Edition.

I did `attrs="{'invisible': [('x_picking_type_name','=', 'Internal Transfers')]}"`, where `x_picking_type_name` is a custom field in the model. I am able to hide values in the records but the column remains in other picking types.

I suppose, there is a way around with context but I could not make it work. I will appreciate any help on this.

The XML I am using. I am trying it in original view without inheriting.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree decoration-info="state == 'draft'" decoration-muted="state == 'cancel'" decoration-danger="state not in ('cancel', 'done') and min_date &lt; current_date" string="Picking list">
    <field name="name"/>
    <field name="location_dest_id"/>
    <field name="partner_id"/>
    <field name="date" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="min_date"/>
    <field name="origin"/>
    <field name="x_picking_type_name"/>
    <field name="check_todo" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_picking_type_name','!=', 'Internal Transfers')]}"/>
    <field name="group_id" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="backorder_id"/>
    <field name="state"/>
    <field name="priority" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="picking_type_id" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="product_id"/>
</tree>
```

Comment: What is the `type` of the `x_picking_type_name` field?

Comment: Type: char, 
Related Field: picking_type_id.name

Comment: This should work; can you please paste the whole customized view in your question?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas It works and hides the field at the record level. But the column header stays. I want the column header to be invisible too.
Updating the question with the xml.

Comment: I asked this on Odoo Forum too. And the reply I got is: this is not possible. 
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/display-a-field-in-tree-view-depending-on-value-of-another-field-in-the-model-137108

Comment: Sure it's all possible, but you have to fiddle with JavaScript and extend list (static/src/js/views/list in the web addon). Unfortunately I have no time to experiment to come up with a solution though

Answer (score 0):

According to this post
https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/how-to-add-a-field-conditional-to-tree-view-of-customer-14707#answer_198626

```
`attrs="{'invisible':[('customer','!=',True)]}"`
```